# Read file with daily date in the file name

Tags: r, date, csv

Every day I receive a file with the daily date in it, for instance: res_20161216.csv

I have no idea how to automatically read every day a file with the daily date in it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in the same working directory as the files to be read, then the name of file is as follows. Else you will need to check what your working directory is using `getwd()`

```
nameOfFile <- paste0("res_", format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d"),".csv")
data <- read.csv(nameOfFile)
```

Comment: It  was such an obvious solution! I must be really tired. Thanks for being to prompt!

Answer (score 2):

```
filename <- paste0("res_", gsub("-","",Sys.Date()))    
data <- read.csv(paste0(filename, ".csv"))

# to rename the data with the date
assign(filename, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a python script that will read the file for you - and do some necessary things :) This part I assume is easy for you. The hard part is - how to make this auto.

Well - I think the easiest will be to set up cron - to run your script once a day. You will find many articles in the web of how to set up cron;

Here for example: [cron tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800);

This is the easiest way - because I think that all (or almost all) unix like system have cron already installed;

Little bit harder but still possible - is to use celery for it; But this can be just too much for you - to run celery you gonna need some redis/rabitmq; learn it and fight a little with configuration; For celery you can start [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html)

The another way - is to use some server for that, if I remember well - you can set up periodic calls in eg.: twisted; The problem is again - some learning curve if you hadn't working with it previously. You can read more here: [Twisted time events](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/core/howto/time.html)

Hope this will help you, 
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in single step

```
df <- read.csv(paste("E:/res_",gsub("-","",Sys.Date()),".csv",sep = ""), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```