# Rename a File Every Day, Using the Current Date as Part of the File Name

Tags: r

I have a file that has the name BackupFile-08072018.cvs, where the 06072018 represents yesterday’s date. Each morning I would like to run my daily code and at the end the out put name of my file should uses today’s date: BackupFile-09072018.cvs. How can I code that ?

```
output_wb <- paste(output_dir,"BackupFile-08072018.cvs",sep="")
```

Comment: I guess this is close enough to be a duplicate: *[Read file with daily date in the file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179667/read-file-with-daily-date-in-the-file-name)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df1 <- mtcars 
setwd("...") # replace the dots with the appropriate folder where you want to save your file each day
write.csv(df1, paste0("BackUpFile-", format(as.Date(Sys.Date() - 1), "%d.%m.%Y"), ".csv"))
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but can I have something like "09.07.2018" ? And I would like to know if it possible to put the date of yesterday "08.07.2018" instead of today

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can create both folder and file name using current date by using paste() function.

```
 mainDir <- "C:/File-Path/"  ### Define main Directory
 subDir <- paste("outputDirectory-",Sys.Date()) ### Define sub Directory using current date
 dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE) ### Create sub directory inside main directory
 setwd(file.path(mainDir, subDir)) ### change the working directory 
 write.csv(df,paste("C:/File-Path/",subDir,"/request--",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep = ""),row.names = F) ### write your csv file inside sub directory.
```

You may ignore the top 4 steps if you do not want to create a new folder each day.